# plot with datetime type in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I try to plot the distribution of "time" feature .
Here is my dataframe :

```
date    amount
40  2018-12-31  104.588094
184     2019-01-01  2487.714459
80  2019-01-02  250.405264
10  2019-01-03  217.385350
170     2019-01-04  208.067521
110     2019-01-05  176.668830
73  2019-01-06  311.626595
145     2019-01-07  283.241003
139     2019-01-08  284.652009
```

Date column is a date type.
Here is my code :

```
#visualizations of time 
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.title('Distribution of Time Feature')
sns.distplot(montant_df_pandas['dateTransmission'])
```

But I get this error :

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         2 plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
>         3 plt.title('Distribution of Time Feature')
>   ----> 4 sns.distplot(montant_df_pandas['dateTransmission'])
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py
>   in distplot(a, bins, hist, kde, rug, fit, hist_kws, kde_kws, rug_kws,
>   fit_kws, color, vertical, norm_hist, axlabel, label, ax)
>       196             line, = ax.plot(0, a.mean())
>       197         else:
>   --> 198             line, = ax.plot(a.mean(), 0)
>       199         color = line.get_color()
>       200         line.remove()
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/naboo-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py
>   in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
>        73             is_float16_result = True
>        74 
>   ---> 75     ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
>        76     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
>        77         ret = um.true_divide(
>
> TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('

Any idea to help me please?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like a date conversion issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379053/typeerror-ufunc-subtract-cannot-use-operands-with-types-dtypem8ns-and-dt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a date conversion issue between numpy and the other libraries [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9610). I tried using a simple workaround for the problem. I am not sure about what was the actual plot we needed to generate but I gave it a shot(hope this helps).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': days, 'Amount': data})


df.set_index('Date')['Amount'].plot(legend=True)
```

Image of the output is attached here
[image: Image of the output is attached here]