# Add trendline for timeseries graph

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, trendline

I want to add a trendline for a timeseries graph in python, that means my x-axis (Datum) has the format of `datetime64[ns]`, when I am following this thread: [How to add trendline in python matplotlib dot (scatter) graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447191/how-to-add-trendline-in-python-matplotlib-dot-scatter-graphs)

and run my code:

```
import numpy as np
#Trendlines
z = np.polyfit(df1['Datum'], df1['Score'], 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
```

I get the **error:**

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('

How can I solve this? This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379053/typeerror-ufunc-subtract-cannot-use-operands-with-types-dtypem8ns-and-dt) also did not help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workaround is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
x = mdates.date2num(df1['Datum'])
y= df1['Score']
z = np.polyfit(x, df1['Score'], 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
#then the plot
df1.plot('Datum', 'Score')
plt.plot(x, p(x), "r--")
```

Gives the outcome with the line plot and the trendline

Answer (score 0):

```
#  date         value
# 01-01-2021    141937
# 01-02-2021    41204
# 01-03-2021    2198991
# 01-04-2021    8744873
# 01-09-2021    7825446

x = df['date']
x = pd.to_datetime(x)
plt.scatter(x, y)

y = df['value'].tolist()
x = dates.date2num(list(pd.to_datetime(x)))
z = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(a['date']), p(x), "r--")
```

Comment: can you explain what is `a['date']` and where did it come from? Also what is `dates` ?