# Add trend line to datetime matplotlib line graph

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe df:

```
times = pd.date_range(start="2018-09-09",end="2020-02-02")
values = np.random.rand(512)

# Make df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time' : times, 
                   'Value': values})
```

And I can plot this easily using plt.plot:

[image: plot1]

But now I want to add a trendline. I tried using some answers:

[How can I draw scatter trend line on matplot? Python-Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635448/how-can-i-draw-scatter-trend-line-on-matplot-python-pandas)

Which doesn't work:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'
```

Then I found the following question and answer:

[TypeError: ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379053/typeerror-ufunc-subtract-cannot-use-operands-with-types-dtypem8ns-and-dt)

But these don't work as well. There my understanding of the issue stops, and I can't find anything else.

My code so far:

```
# Get values for the trend line analysis
x = df['Time'].dt.to_pydatetime()

# Calculate a fit line
trend = np.polyfit(x, df['Value'], 1)
fit = np.poly1d(trend)

# General plot again
figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(x, df['Value'])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Value')

# Now trendline
plt.plot(x, fit(x), "r--")

# And show
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should provide a constructor for your input (to have enough data and reproducible types)

Comment: I will try, but this dataset has been delivered to not sure how easily I can reproduce it.

Comment: I got it working, will update with reproducible example.

Comment: Updated with reproducible dataframe, the same error applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to convert the dates using matplotlib's [date2num()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) function and its counterpart the [num2date](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date) function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as dates

np.random.seed(123)
times = pd.date_range(start="2018-09-09",end="2020-02-02")
values = np.random.rand(512)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time' : times, 
                   'Value': values})


# Get values for the trend line analysis
x_dates = df['Time']
x_num = dates.date2num(x_dates)

# Calculate a fit line
trend = np.polyfit(x_num, df['Value'], 1)
fit = np.poly1d(trend)

# General plot again
#figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(x_dates, df['Value'])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Value')

# Not really necessary to convert the values back into dates
#but added as a demonstration in case one wants to plot non-linear curves
x_fit = np.linspace(x_num.min(), x_num.max())
plt.plot(dates.num2date(x_fit), fit(x_fit), "r--")

# And show
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can omit the first part of .dt.to_datetime, it works without. Clean simple solution

Comment: Good catch. I have integrated this.